# Percentage calculation on array variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have an input like the following

```
Topic   Current Log     Lag
abc     324     22345   235
xyz     552     48453   1055
bcd     673     100546  3567
```

My requirement is to find the percentage difference between the values of Log and Lag

And if the percentage is greater than 30, i need the whole line to printed on some file.

Applying the whole percentage formula on a if statement like below doesn't work.

```
if [${log_array[$i]} - ${lag_array[$j] * 100 / ${log_array[i]} -gt 30]
```

if [ 100 - 70 * 100 / 100 > 30] i need that line to be printed.

How to process this percentage calculation on arrays in shell script?

Comment: Why don't you just use awk for this?

Comment: i have used awk '{print $3}' and awk '{print $4}'  from the txt file and saved the values in the variable log_array and lag_array.

Comment: You wrote `greater than 30` but used `-gt 20`. Which one is it? Also, the formula doesn't look like it would compute the *"percentage difference"*. Please specify what you mean by that. It would be best to give an example like *"123 and 456 have a percentage difference of ..."*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already use `awk` to create the arrays `log_array` and `lag_array` I'd recommend to do everything in a single `awk` command. This is not only shorter to write and faster to execute, but also more precise as `awk` supports floating point numbers whereas `bash` does not.

```
awk 'NR>1 && ($3-$4)/$3 > 0.3' inputFile
```

This reads the table from `inputFile` and prints those lines where the difference *Log-Lag* is greater than 30 % of *Log*.

If you also want to print the percentage use

```
awk 'NR>1 && (p=($3-$4)/$3)>0.3 {print $0, p}' inputFile
```

**Note:** I think the formula is wrong as all percentages in your example are greater than 90 %. You didn't exactly specify how the *"percentage difference"* should be computed. However, I suspect the following:

*Log-Lag* is *H* percent of *Log*:
`Log * H/100 = Log-Lag`, therefore `H = (Log-Lag)/Log * 100`
Now compute the difference *D* between 100% (the "percentage" of *Log*) and *H*:
`D = 100-H`

In this case the script would be

```
awk 'NR>1 && (p=1-($3-$4)/$3)>0.3 {print $0, p}' inputFile
```

Comment: This method almost works but its not doing the math operation perfectly.  Also the NR>1 doesn't work. i used NR>10 it gave the me the results but also showed me the values which are less than 30%.

Comment: `its not doing the math operation perfectly`. Please explain: What inputs where used? What did the program do? What did you expect? `NR>1 doesn't work. i used NR>10`. Is your table preceded by 10 non-data lines?

Comment: There is value like 77523 on the log and 5000 on the lag, if you see the percentage of 5000 in 77k it is less than 10% this value is also getting displayed in the output. In the NR part the data is actually there from the very first line but it is picking that..

Comment: `the percentage of 5000 in 77k it is less than 10%`. That sounds like you are not interested in the *"percentage difference"* mentioned in your question, because the *difference* between 10% and 100% is totally greater than 30%.

Comment: it worked perfectly awk `'NR>4 && ($4-$5)*100/$4 < 70' lag.txt` when i set the NR value as 4, but when i use it on other files which are having huge text entries on column 1 getting an error like `awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=lag.txt FNR=30) fatal: division by zero attempted`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the loss in precision coming from the fact that bash does not support floating point or fractional arithmetic, you can do a

```
if (( ${log_array[$i]} - ${lag_array[$j] * 100 / ${log_array[i]} > 20 ))
then
  ...
fi
```

Comment: I know you just fixed OP's formula so that it executes. However, I think the formula itself is wrong too as `-` has lower precedence than `*` and `/`.

Comment: Hint: Inside arithmetic contexts like `(( ))` and `array[ ]` you don't need the `$`. It can even hurt to have the `$` there, for instance `i=5; (( $i++ ))` fails.

Comment: @Socowi : I new it for simple variables, but was not aware that it would work for arrays too.

Comment: @Socowi : The formula looks mathematically odd to me too, but I assumed that the OP knows what he wants to calculate, especially since the precedence rules in bash are the same as the usual ones in mathematics. More seriously is the typo in the second operand, where he probably meant `log_array` and not `lag_array`.